# How to change TImage programatically on TButton click?

Tags: image, delphi, firemonkey

I need to change the image from a few `TImage` components on my main Form.

- What are the possible ways to change it *programatically*?

Comment: Could someone at least please explain the downvote?

Comment: what a *resource image* is supposed to be? Do you mean change the `TImage` picture from a resource file?

Comment: Yes. Why is it so enigmatic?

Comment: Because a `TImage` does not have a *resource*. Anyway you can load a different image resource in the button `OnClick` event, then make an image from the resource and assign the image to the `TImage` `Picture` property

Comment: That's pretty much what I would expect from an answer. Still don't understand why so many downvotes, think simple people.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I agree with who did. I think your question is pretty unclear and lacks of what here's call an [mcve]. Sorry :)

Comment: A `TImage` is a control which itself is not an actual image. Its `Picture` property is what you're looking for. There are many ways to change this resource, but without knowing the source, I don't know which method you want. For example, you could say `Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(MyFilename);`, or perhaps `Image1.Picture.Assign(MyGraphic);` or `Image1.Picture.LoadFromStream(MyStream);` In any case, this has nothing to do with a button click.

Comment: Instead of calling us "simple", perhaps it would be better to understand why people find your question unclear, and improve it in an edit.

Comment: I'm not calling anyone simple; I'm telling you guys to *think* simple. Do not complicate. I have a `TImage` and I want to change it's image on a `TButton` click. Simple.

Comment: Referring back to my last comment, I was almost sure there was `TPicture.LoadFromStream` but it appears that is wrong.

Comment: Rather than expecting us all to adapt our thinking to yours (when it's not at all clear from your original post what your thinking was), perhaps you should consider writing clearer questions. Your task is to help us understand the question you're asking, so we can try to answer it. It's not our responsibility to try and figure out what you really intend to ask when you post something that isn't clear or that makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following, where your resource of type `RCDATA` is named `JpgImage_1`.

The resource is here supposed to be linked to the executable via the [`$RESOURCE`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Resource_file_(Delphi)) directive.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  stream: TStream;
begin
  if FindResource(HInstance, PChar('JpgImage_1'), RT_RCDATA) = 0 then
    Exit;

  stream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'JpgImage_1', RT_RCDATA);
  try
    Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(stream);
  finally
    stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The question is tagged with FireMonkey, but `TImage` does not have a `Picture` or `Picture.Graphic` property in FireMonkey, only a `Bitmap` property.  But in VCL, `TImage.Picture.Bitmap` only supports BMP images, not JPG images, thus the need to `Assign()` a `TJPEGImage` object, but it should be `Picture.Assign(jpg)` instead of `Picture.Bitmap.Assign(jpg)`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you're right: I did my test in a VCL form. I did the monkey with no fire! Thank you for pointing me out. Answer edited